.NET Core : IFormFile sometimes returns NULL
IFormFile sometimes is NULL (but some time it works) while uploading the same docx file (45 kb).

My input type file name is same as IFormFile parameter
Have used <form> tag to post the file with enctype="multipart/form-data"
Used RequestFormLimits, formoptions parameters in program.cs

But still facing issue of IFormFile parameter sometimes being NULL.
This is my code:
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataFromFile(IFormFile fileUpload)
{
    if (fileUpload != null)
    {
        var fPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        var fName = Path.GetFileName(fPath);
        var fExt = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);
    
        if (fExt.ToUpper() == ".PDF" || fExt.ToUpper() == ".DOCX")
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000);

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var stream = fileUpload.OpenReadStream();
            fName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName);
            content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "pdf_file", fName);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("URL", content);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var getAllSentences = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject(getAllSentences);
            var allSentences = responseObject.groups;

            return Ok(allSentences);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound("Please upload pdf or word document (docx) file.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound("Please upload valid file.");
    }
}



IFormFile sometimes is NULL (but some time it works) while uploading
the same docx file (45 kb).

Well, according to your scenario, description and from shared code snippet it seems that your code is correct because the issue is intermittent.
The issue you are having might be caused by a few factors, so keeping that into consideration, we need to investigate few stuff instead of offering any direct solution.
First of all, by default, ASP.NET Core has limitations on request size. You've mentioned using RequestFormLimits in program.cs. Examine your configuration to ensure the allowed request size is sufficient for your 45kb docx file.
I am not sure what about your current size configuration but, you could increase it up to 100MB as by using MultipartBodyLengthLimit following:
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600;
});

Note: If you need larger size then configure it accordingly. You could check here.
Apart from that, one thing is very crucial which is determine if there are any patterns when the IFormFile is NULL. Does it happen only on certain browsers, file sizes, or specific scenarios? We need to find that out comparing the log or reproducing the scenario over and over again.
In this case, you may use browser developer tools to inspect the network traffic. Ensure that the file is being sent in the request payload. If there is any application log or IIS log that could also be very helpful.
In addition, although at the begining you have stated that, you have used enctype="multipart/form-data", correct file type and file name. However, please double check these once again and most imporantly double check your server configuration if anything you are missing about.
Note: As you also haven't mentioned which server you are running your application on, please double check the configuration, specifically its limit or current configuration. I would highly recommend you to refer this official document.

Hi Md Farid Uddin Kiron,
Thanks for the answer.
Actually i am getting following error in console (for some docx files).
https://localhost:7089/controller/method net::ERR_FAILED

Could you please share more details what the error is all about, I can't see what's the details of net::ERR_FAILED
